# Get lines that start with the same characters

Tags: regex

```
I have a file that looks like this:

    acquaintances       Bekanta
    acquaintances       Bekant
    acquaintances       Bekanting
    acquaintances       Bekantskap
    acquaintances       Umgängesvän
    acquaintances       vänkrets
    acquaintances       vänkretsen
    adoption        Adoption
    adoption        Adoptionen
    adoption        Adoptioner
    adoption        Adoptering
    ...

and I want to make it look like this:

acquaintances:      Bekanta
                    Bekant
                    Bekanting
                    Bekantskap
                    Umgängesvän
                    vänkrets
                vänkretsen
adoption:       Adoption
                Adoptionen
                Adoptioner
                Adoptering
```

(the different indents are intentional)

I have been trying to figure out how to select lines that start with a new word and replace them. This is the closes I got, but it doesn't work:

```
Find:
^(.*?)  (.*?)   (.*?)
\1  (.*?)   (.*?)

Replace:
$1  $2  $3
    $4  $5
```

Comment: sublime text, but If I can get a sample in any tool, I can probably figure it out :)

Comment: AFAIK, most text editors cannot handle repeated groups. So unless you have an exact number of lines, this becomes a hard problem to solve using a text editor. If you use a programming language, it wouldn't be that difficult. Here's the regex that can match the group of text `^\s*([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)(\s*\1\s+([^\s]+)){1,}`

Comment: The best I can suggest is [`^ *(\w+)\t\t\w+(?:\R *\t\t\w+)*\R\K( *)\1\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Mk2v0K/1) and replace with 4 spaces and then `$2` (`"    $2"` without `"`s). Then, you need to click Replace all as many times as necessary until no match is found. The main problem is that the indentation space number cannot be a variable, so uou can't make the indentation work as you wish. And of course there is a problem with no variable width lookbehind.